# Programming Externally Linked Images in Excel

Tags: python, excel, http, hyperlink, openpyxl

This may be a long shot, but I figured it's worth asking. I need a way to programmatically insert **externally linked** images in excel, meaning that every time you open the file, the spreadsheet will contact the url at which the image is located. It's easy to do this manually in excel, but I want to do it programmatically, preferably with python. I've tried using the openpyxl and XlsxWriter libraries, but neither have this specific functionality. My only other option is to look for the excel source code so I can see how an externally linked image is represented by excel. I don't suppose Microsoft makes that source code public, do they?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Not sure about python, but VBA should be able to do this:  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?387841-Display-image-from-internet-in-a-Picturebox.  If handled by python, you would have to run the py script everytime.  EDIT: maybe this? https://code.google.com/p/pyinex/

Comment: "It's easy to do this manually in excel". Are you certain of that? I can see how to insert images from the web in Excel 2007 (and that can be done by XlsxWriter) but I cannot see how to insert an image that updates every time the file is opened.

Comment: This is third the post with the same content! Microsoft doesn't make the source code of Excel available but the file specification is available. I haven't looked at all the possibilities (this particular part of the specification is particularly arcane) but would accept a PR for openpyxl if it worked.

You might, however, find that a macro is the best way to do this.

Comment: @CharlieClark I'm aware. Those questions were all from me, and I realize that you are one of the main contributors to openpyxl, so I thank you for your responses and commend you on the robustness of the library! However, none of the excel/readers and writers available seem to accomplish this goal, although after looking at the XML structure of an excel document with an externally linked image, it doesn't seem that far-fetched. With openpyxl, it seems that you CAN fetch an image from the web and embed it, but LINKING that image to the server it was requested from is not possible.

Comment: @jmcnamara Yes, it's possible. When inserting an image, first type in the url of the image where you would normally input a filepath, then simply click on the arrow on the right side of the "insert button" and choose "insert and link". I have tested this extensively.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. @Will You are correct. This is easily done with macros, but the constraints of my project do not allow me to use VBA.

Comment: Discussion about implementation in a particular library should be carried out on a bug tracker or a mailing list.